# Difference in behavior between Xcode and OTA Ad-hoc distribution

Tags: debugging, core-data, core-audio, ota, xcdatamodel

I have my app working to my satisfaction both in the simulator and on two devices when debugging through Xcode 4.3.2. I use OTA Ad-hoc distribution to send to my beta testers. After archiving, saving, and uploading my ipa and plist file to my website, I then download and successfully install the app on my phone.

Sounds good, right?

HOWEVER, I am using CoreAudio and CoreData, and low and behold suddenly there is no sound in my app. I delete and install OTA on the same devices I am debugging with, so I am at a loss to where the problem is occurring.

I have a feeling that there might be an underlying problem with my Core Data model (which feeds my sound) but checks upon checks seem to verify that it is working. It DOES work when I install from Xcode, unplug, close, and reopen the app on the device. Only the OTA install has this problem.

Has anyone encountered any differences in behavior like this? I checked my build settings and the only difference I see for AdHoc is using the Entitlements.plist, which only useful setting appears to be NO to debugging.

Comment: Update - rebuilt my coreData model and also tried raising my target OS, it appears as if my coreAudio buffer isn't moving... I'll look into it.

Comment: Furthermore, I can recreate the problem if I run as a profile straight from xCode, so now I'm thinking it must have something to do with adhoc vs debug settings, except I don't know where to begin to look.

Comment: OK, I checked everything that was different between the build settings and made them match debugging. Apparently, when I finally turned off speed and size optimizations for the Adhoc settings, my app works as expected. My file size went from 3.4MB to 3.46MB, and my app works as intended. Whew! Hopefully this conversation with myself may be of use to somebody someday. :)

Comment: You should add this as an answer so it's easier for people to see the solution.